# nswag error in .NET 5.0, Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException

Tags: swagger, aspnetboilerplate, nswag, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, aspnetzero

I am using aspnetzero framework. After upgrading .Net core  to .Net5, I am facing an issue when running refresh.bat. It's throwing below mentioned error

> Executing file '..\EMA.Web.Host\nswag\service.config.nswag' with
> variables 'Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException.
> child_process.js:656
> throw err;'

> Error: Command failed: dotnet "E:....\node_modules\nswag\bin/binaries/NetCore21/dotnet-> nswag.dll"

nswag version updated to 13.12.1.

When I run 'http://localhost:5000/swagger/v1/swagger.json', I am getting updated json.

Not sure why its causing Stack overflow exception, any pointers to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Can your post the code from `refresh.bat`?

Comment: @Helen, I was able to resolve this exception, type JObject and JToken were causing this stackoverflow exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type JObject and JToken were causing this stackoverflow exception, removing them fixed the error.